# Create multi-line input

Tags: vba, input

We have a custom macro set up in our (health service) CRM which lets us send ad hoc text messages to clients.

It opens as a one line input box, with options for 'OK' and 'Cancel'.

[image]

We often send long-ish messages and it's painful not being able to see what you have written all at once.

I've found the code that includes the title of the input box and the prompt next to the field where you type:

```
set msgEntryDlg = CreateDialog("Adhoc SMS")
set msgTxtCtl = msgEntryDlg.AddControl("SMS Message: ",2, "")
```

Is there something I can add to this to force it to show a bigger/multi-line input box?

Comment: In my opinion your best option is to create your own userform. You'll be able to make it look and feel exatly as you want.

Comment: There is no multi-line `InputBox` function. You have to create your own custom form and put some code on it.